# UX smart contract trigger

Tags: ether, tokens, gas

I want to know if my use case can be implemented on Ethereum network's smart contracts.

This is my use case:

A P2P app (similar to torrent clients) installed on PC or phone

1. I (sender) click on a send button on my client app
2. a data packet is sent from my device to a destination device using a P2P network, at the same time this triggers Smart contract A between sender and receiver.
3. When data packet is received by receiver, it check the authenticity of the data packet
4. Receiver client app sends the result of the authenticity check to the smart contract A
5. If the data received is authentic, smart contract takes X ETH amount from receiver wallet and send it to sender wallet. If not contract is over without nothing

Is such a use case manageable using smart contracts, does it require external components, and what should I expect in term of gas.

Thanks a lot for your help.